# What does this url parameter do in python scapy?

Tags: python

```
from scapy.all import *
my_packet = IP(src='127.0.0.1', dst='127.0.0.1')
send(my_packet, verbose=60)
```

What does verbose do ? even if i try to translate the word it gives me another meaning in my native language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `verbose` parameter controls whether the function displays any information. If you set `verbose` to 0 or False, the function will generate no information. If you set it to some positive value, then the function will display relevant progress information.  The higher the value, the higher the verbosity i.e. more information is displayed.

In this particular example, you are invoking the `send` function to send packets.  If you set `verbose` to 0 then no messages will be displayed about the packets being set.  If you set `verbose` to `600` as in your code example, it will display messages indicating the success/failure of sending each packet.

Answer (score 0):

Verbosity tells how detailed the output of the command will be. The higher the verbose value, the more detail it will output about what it's doing. This is in most cases useful when you are trying to figure out why something isn't working properly.